# Sql Server Query To Group By Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following data from 2 tables Notes (left) and scans (right) :

[image]

Imagine the picker and packers were all varying, like you can have `JOHN, JANE` etc.

I need a query that outputs like so :

On a given `date range` :

```
Name - Picked (units) - Packed (units)
MASI - 15 - 21
JOHN - 21 - 32
```

etc.

I can't figure out how to even start this, any tips will be helpful thanks.

Comment: Do you also have a "Person" table?  That lists 'Masi' and 'John' on seperate rows?

Comment: @Dems Nope. There is no other table.

Comment: What is the relation between two tables ?

Comment: @Sudhakar The "number" on the left connects to "picknote" on the right. -- not the id's sorry.

Comment: You mean ID column on both sides? and also picked one is left and packed is right side table ? If picked one is left then Sum(Units) is picked ? Count(*) on right is packed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a "worker" take that lists each Picker/Packer individually, I think you'd need something like this...

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN action.name = 'Picker' THEN scans.Picker ELSE scans.Packer END  AS worker,
  SUM(CASE WHEN action.name = 'Picker' THEN notes.Units  ELSE 0            END) AS PickedUnits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN action.name = 'Packer' THEN notes.Units  ELSE 0            END) AS PackedUnits
FROM
  notes
INNER JOIN
  scans
    ON scans.PickNote = notes.Number
CROSS JOIN
(
            SELECT 'Picker' AS name
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Packer' AS name

)
  AS action
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN action.name = 'Picker' THEN scans.Picker ELSE scans.Packer END
```

*(This is actually just an algebraic re-arrangement of the answer that @RaphaëlAlthaus posted at the same time as me.  Both use `UNION` to work out the Picker values and the Packer values separately.  If you have separate indexes on `scans.Picker` and `scans.Packer` then I would expect mine MAY be slowest.  If you don't have those two indexes then I would expect mine to be fastest.  I recommend creating the indexes and testing on a realtisic data set.)*

**EDIT**

Actually, what I would recommend is a change to scans table completely; normalise it.

- Your de-normalised set has one row per PickNote, with fields `picker` and `packer`.
- A normalised set would have two rows per PickNote with fields `role` and `worker`.

```
  id  | PickNote | Role | Worker
------+----------+------+--------
  01  | PK162675 | Pick |  MASI
  02  | PK162675 | Pack |  MASI
  03  | PK162676 | Pick |  FRED
  04  | PK162676 | Pack |  JOHN
```

This allows you to create simple indexes and simple queries.

You may initially baulk at the extra *unecessary* rows, but it will yield simpler queries, faster queries, better maintainability, increased flexibility, etc, etc.

In short, this normalisation may cost a little extra space, but it pays back dividends forever.

Comment: Sql looks a bit deep for me but works perfectly, but how can I specify the date range? Also it needs to only pick up those from Notes table that have a processedOn time (it can be null -- when its only partially picked or packed).

Comment: @MuhammadA - Adding `WHERE notes.processedOn >= '20120101' AND notes.processedOn < '20120201'` before the `GROUP BY` will filter out any `notes` records that have `NULL` date, or a date outside of your range.

Comment: Your suggestion of normalising is very valuable :) any other suggestions? Is it a good idea to have the picker and packer names into a seperate table where they are unique?

Comment: @MuhammadA - As a general rule, using something's name as a key or identifies is a bad idea.  What if they change name?  You have to update every record everywhere.  So, yes, have a `workers` table, with a unique id for each, then fields for name, etc.  Then use the id in your other tables.  The id will never change, and changing their name will never have any consequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, SUM(nbPicked) Picked, SUM(nbPacked) Packed
FROM
(SELECT n.Picker name, SUM(n.Units) nbPicked, 0 nbPacked 
FROM Notes n
INNER JOIN scans s ON s.PickNote = n.Number
--WHERE s.ProcessedOn BETWEEN x and y
GROUP BY n.Picker

UNION ALL

SELECT n.Packer name, 0 nbPicked, SUM(n.Units) nbPacked
FROM Notes n
INNER JOIN scans s ON s.PickNote= n.Number
--WHERE s.ProcessedOn BETWEEN x and y
GROUP BY n.Packer)

GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: +1 : But I would add that `UNION ALL` will have a lower overhead as it won't even attempt to de-dupe the two result sets.